# Facing this issue whenever adding permissions. and what i do code instead on comment lines?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// TODO: Consider calling

//ActivityCompat#requestPermissions

// here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding

//   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
int[] grantResults)

// to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation

for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.

return;

```
            }
```

- 

---

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When i Entered above method.. android ide send bydefault code .. in above code there are some comments line ..what will be the code in that space.